# How to change the time when applying rules of outlook 2013

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2013, rules

I'm looking for a way to change the time when applying my rules of outlook 2013.

For example, i want to move mails to a folder when i change categorize of mail.But when i edit the rule, outlook prompts

`apply this rule after the message arrives`.

But this isn't my case, because i may change the categorize after days when i received mails. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

In Outlook 2013, you can set up a Quick Step to apply a category AND move the message to the folder simultaneously.

On the home ribbon

- click on **quick steps**
- then **new quick step**
- then **custom**

In the dialog that appears

- **Rename** the quick step
- under the action select **Categorize Message**
- then **choose category**
- click **add action**
- choose **move to folder**
- then chose the folder you want to move the categorized file to

You can also chose a shortcut key to press to automate it even more.